# PhoneGap – Page "zooms" out of viewport by rotation

Tags: android, cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, phonegap, muse

i'm pretty new to PhoneGap.
For my first project I designed a website with Adobe Muse and built it into an APK with a normal, empty PhoneGap-Project.
It works very well, but when I rotate my Device (it is a tablet and the app is only meant to run on a tablet with Android 5.0) I experience strange problems with my web page "zooming" out of display on the right and the bottom.
And every time I rotate it back and forth, it zooms one step more out of the viewport.

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUuDC.jpg)
[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOkRI.jpg)
[Pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7xTt.jpg)

Does someone know this problem - or even better - a solution?
Will be very thankful for every hint!

Edit:
I used PhoneGap-Build.
No plugins or something were used.
I have slider widgets (the ones from Muse) on the pages where the error occurs.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Is it possible to see some code? It would help to the people who's able to give you answer.

Comment: Would you specify which pieces of code would help?

Comment: You should know it, I suppose the one that responsible for re-write UI/state when device rotated.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> is what Muse has written in every page.<br>
I tried to replace it with <meta name=“viewport“ content=“width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0″ /> but have the same issue.